# Issue with 2 stage authentication on new Apple iPhone and MacBook Air

Tags: iphone, apple-id, user-account, two-step-authentication

I am quite the predicament and my Google searches have not been fruitful at all.

I have an iPhone 5 that has now decided to not go past the Apple logo and won't turn on. It appears the battery is swelling and pushing the screen out.

I have borrowed an iPhone 6 off a friend and have restored an old backup from the 5 which was fine.

I travel a lot and as a result have different SIM cards (many) in various places. At some point I have accepted the 2 stage authentication process with Apple but now have no idea what the phone number is attached to this process and did not make a note of the recovery code (or cannot find it anywhere).

I attempted to log in using my Apple ID and have subsequently been locked out. I do not know the phone number to unlock the account.

I have phoned Apple support and they advise I need that phone number.

My iPhone 5 is the only trusted device I have other than my Macbook but feel even if I gain access it will advise my account is locked and need to know the trusted phone number to unlock.

The Find my Phone is switched on so I cannot even do a restore on the phone using iTunes unless this is deactivated and again needs the apple account unlocked.

I am at a complete loss and have no way of accessing all the necessary areas to set the new phone up.

If anyone has any experience with this or knows a workaround I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Your workaround is to create a new iCloud account and set your new phone up using that account, then copy contacts, calendar entries and so on manually from your MacBook.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this is now what I'm attempting to do. The issue is I restored a backup from my Macbook from old phone and now it wants that iCloud, Apple ID, iTunes login from the old account which is now locked out. I don't have any record of the phone number attached to it so cannot unlock the account and as a result am unable to close down the Find my phone option which would then let me restore the phone to setup with new account. I get the security but this is crazy as I can prove the account is mine but there is no way of doing this with Apple customer service. Any ideas most welcome mate.

Comment: Have you tried putting the phone into DFU mode? Instructions here: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-put-an-iphone-in-dfu-mode-3628686/

Comment: Thanks Mike, I hadn't tried that (or knew about it). Trying it now and so far appears to be working. Will let you know :)